# gcc error compiling templated classes with large number of template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, compilation

I am having issue in compiling code having templated classes nested within other templated classes. The major templated class, called `MyClass` has 50 template arguments accepting a default class type called `null_type_nn` doing nothing specific.

My template arguments start all with the '_' character like below

```
     template< 
         class T0=null_type_0
       , class T1=null_type_1
       , ...
       , class T50=null_type_50
     > MyClass;

     typedef MyClass< _MyClassB, _MyClassC > _MyClass1;
     typedef MyClass< _MyClassD, _MyClassE > _MyClass2;
     .....
     typedef MyClass< _MyClass1, _MyClass2, _MyClass3 , ..._MyClass50> my_type_a;
```

If I don't call a certain member function of the class I don't have the error below; If I just construct a message and then access/use one of its data member I have no problem.

What I can do to sort it out or help the compiler in its job?

```
       : Assembler messages:
       :8851: Error: symbol `_ZN12mine_structIL10EncodingID5015ELS0_1011E11
       AsciiStringLS0_1115E23AsciiAlphaNumericStringLS0_1130ES2_LS0_1019E6S
       Int16LS0_1066ES2_LS0_5030E11mine_unionILm1ES_ILS0_5042ELS0_15ES1_
       LS0_16404E11mine_arrayILm4ES_ILS0_20ELS0_18ES2_LS0_1078ES3_LS0_2ES3_
       LS0_19E5Dec32LS0_16E6SInt32LS0_64005E12mine_null_5LS0_64006E12
       mine_null_6LS0_64007E12mine_null_7LS0_64008E12mine_null_8LS0_64009E12
       mine_null_9LS0_64010E13mine_null_10LS0_64011E13mine_null_11LS0_64012E13
       mine_n...// continues..it is a very big error!
```

The complete error log is the following

`: Assembler messages:
:972: Error: symbol _ZN12main_structIL10EncodingID5067ELS0_5037ES_ILS0_5037ELS0_1099E6SInt16LS0_1059ES1_LS0_1036E6SInt64LS0_1037ES2_LS0_1089E6SInt32LS0_1070E10ByteStreamLS0_1095ES3_LS0_1183ES2_LS0_1184ES2_LS0_64009E12main_null_9LS0_64010E13main_null_10LS0_64011E13main_null_11LS0_64012E13main_null_12LS0_64013E13main_null_13LS0_64014E13main_null_14LS0_64015E13main_null_15LS0_64016E13main_null_16LS0_64017E13main_null_17LS0_64018E13main_null_18LS0_64019E13main_null_19LS0_64020E13main_null_20LS0_64021E13main_null_21LS0_64022E13main_null_22LS0_64023E13main_null_23LS0_64024E13main_null_24LS0_64025E13main_null_25LS0_64026E13main_null_26LS0_64027E13main_null_27LS0_64028E13main_null_28LS0_64029E13main_null_29LS0_64030E13main_null_30LS0_64031E13main_null_31LS0_64032E13main_null_32LS0_64033E13main_null_33LS0_64034E13main_null_34LS0_64035E13main_null_35LS0_64036E13main_null_36LS0_64037E13main_null_37LS0_64038E13main_null_38LS0_64039E13main_null_39LS0_64040E13main_null_40LS0_64041E13main_null_41LS0_64042E13main_null_42LS0_64043E13main_null_43LS0_64044E13main_null_44LS0_64045E13main_null_45LS0_64046E13main_null_46LS0_64047E13main_null_47LS0_64048E13main_null_48ELS0_21449E11main_unionILm50ES_ILS0_5016ELS0_1038ES3_LS0_1118ES3_LS0_1017ES3_LS0_1051ES3_LS0_1048ES3_LS0_1014E4DateLS0_1087ES3_LS0_1159ES2_LS0_1008E11AsciiStringLS0_21468E11main_arrayILm4ES_ILS0_5084ELS0_1179ES1C_LS0_1180E23AsciiAlphaNumericStringLS0_64002E12main_null_2LS0_64003E12main_null_3LS0_64004E12main_null_4LS0_64005E12main_null_5LS0_64006E12main_null_6LS0_64007E12main_null_7LS0_64008E12main_null_8LS0_64009ES5_LS0_64010ES6_LS0_64011ES7_LS0_64012ES8_LS0_64013ES9_LS0_64014ESA_LS0_64015ESB_LS0_64016ESC_LS0_64017ESD_LS0_64018ESE_LS0_64019ESF_LS0_64020ESG_LS0_64021ESH_LS0_64022ESI_LS0_64023ESJ_LS0_64024ESK_LS0_64025ESL_LS0_64026ESM_LS0_64027ESN_LS0_64028ESO_LS0_64029ESP_LS0_64030ESQ_LS0_64031ESR_LS0_64032ESS_LS0_64033EST_LS0_64034ESU_LS0_64035ESV_LS0_64036ESW_LS0_64037ESX_LS0_64038ESY
:8191: Error: symbol_ZN12main_structIL10EncodingID5067ELS0_5037ES_ILS0_5037ELS0_1099E6SInt16LS0_1059ES1_LS0_1036E6SInt64LS0_1037ES2_LS0_1089E6SInt32LS0_1070E10ByteStreamLS0_1095ES3_LS0_1183ES2_LS0_1184ES2_LS0_64009E12main_null_9LS0_64010E13main_null_10LS0_64011E13main_null_11LS0_64012E13main_null_12LS0_64013E13main_null_13LS0_64014E13main_null_14LS0_64015E13main_null_15LS0_64016E13main_null_16LS0_64017E13main_null_17LS0_64018E13main_null_18LS0_64019E13main_null_19LS0_64020E13main_null_20LS0_64021E13main_null_21LS0_64022E13main_null_22LS0_64023E13main_null_23LS0_64024E13main_null_24LS0_64025E13main_null_25LS0_64026E13main_null_26LS0_64027E13main_null_27LS0_64028E13main_null_28LS0_64029E13main_null_29LS0_64030E13main_null_30LS0_64031E13main_null_31LS0_64032E13main_null_32LS0_64033E13main_null_33LS0_64034E13main_null_34LS0_64035E13main_null_35LS0_64036E13main_null_36LS0_64037E13main_null_37LS0_64038E13main_null_38LS0_64039E13main_null_39LS0_64040E13main_null_40LS0_64041E13main_null_41LS0_64042E13main_null_42LS0_64043E13main_null_43LS0_64044E13main_null_44LS0_64045E13main_null_45LS0_64046E13main_null_46LS0_64047E13main_null_47LS0_64048E13main_null_48ELS0_21449E11main_unionILm50ES_ILS0_5016ELS0_1038ES3_LS0_1118ES3_LS0_1017ES3_LS0_1051ES3_LS0_1048ES3_LS0_1014E4DateLS0_1087ES3_LS0_1159ES2_LS0_1008E11AsciiStringLS0_21468E11main_arrayILm4ES_ILS0_5084ELS0_1179ES1C_LS0_1180E23AsciiAlphaNumericStringLS0_64002E12main_null_2LS0_64003E12main_null_3LS0_64004E12main_null_4LS0_64005E12main_null_5LS0_64006E12main_null_6LS0_64007E12main_null_7LS0_64008E12main_null_8LS0_64009ES5_LS0_64010ES6_LS0_64011ES7_LS0_64012ES8_LS0_64013ES9_LS0_64014ESA_LS0_64015ESB_LS0_64016ESC_LS0_64017ESD_LS0_64018ESE_LS0_64019ESF_LS0_64020ESG_LS0_64021ESH_LS0_64022ESI_LS0_64023ESJ_LS0_64024ESK_LS0_64025ESL_LS0_64026ESM_LS0_64027ESN_LS0_64028ESO_LS0_64029ESP_LS0_64030ESQ_LS0_64031ESR_LS0_64032ESS_LS0_64033EST_LS0_64034ESU_LS0_64035ESV_LS0_64036ESW_LS0_64037ESX_LS0_64038ESY
make: * [unpack_test] Error 1`

Comment: "`_` followed by capital letter" kind of names are reserved by compiler. It's better not to use them. Also you need to provide the line where the error is generated.

Comment: Are you serious? 50 template arguments?! And the error you posted does not contain any relevant information. Please post the complete text.

Comment: Show the full error, it is of the kind "Error: symbol `long_mangled_symbol_name_here` now the real error message comes here. Sometimes you just have to get your hands dirty and dig into the mess of a compiler output. Don't be afraid. It is just big, but logical. Mostly.

Comment: HI All. The compiler doesn't give me any line at all..just this big big error..give me few minutes and I will post it.

Comment: @Abruzzo Forte: You should show the actual error message you have included a few lines of almost no information and hidden the actual problem. The error message will contain the huge identifier (you can cut most of it out) followed by what the toolchain did not like about it

Comment: just added for you. I think that it doesn't have any information at all. Is there any gcc flags that might highlight some part of the compiling process or logs or whatever that might help?

Comment: What is the target architecture and platform? The error is in the assembler, and that is quite uncommon. It might be that the assembler in your current platform cannot manage identifiers of that length (I believe that in most platforms the maximum length of identifiers in the gcc toolchain was unlimited...)

Comment: Linux lndbxdev01 2.6.24.7-108.el5rt #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Mon Mar 23 10:58:10 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
processor       : 0
  2 vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
  3 cpu family      : 6
  4 model           : 26
  5 model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5570  @ 2.93GHz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From C++ 2003 Standard:

> 17.4.3.2.1 Global names [lib.global.names]
>
> Certain sets of names and function signatures are always reserved to
>   the implementation:
>
> Each name that contains a double underscore (_ _) or begins with an
>   underscore followed by an uppercase letter (2.11) is reserved to the
>   implementation for any use.

`_MyClassB`, `_MyClassC`... are reserved names.

Comment: Though I doubt this causes the error, this is something I wish was more strictly enforced...

Comment: Hi Matthieu...unfortunately you are right..I updated all my class names from '_MyClass' to 'MyClass' and still doesn't work.